# Getting JWT object after authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, feathersjs

I've created an authentication using `feathers generate authentication` and a service that requires authentication using `feathers generate service`.

I haven't done any code changes to this at all.

So I have the following:

```
app.service('authentication').hooks({
  before: {
    create: [
      authentication.hooks.authenticate(config.strategies)
    ],
    remove: [
      authentication.hooks.authenticate('jwt')
    ]
  }
});
```

I was wondering how, after a successful authentication of the JWT token, how can I get that object into my services constructor?

In my service I have:

```
module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [ 
      authenticate('jwt'),
      hook => { console.log(hook.params.payload); } 
    ],
```

Which console logs the payload but I just don't know how to actually save it so my service can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized if you look at the `params` it's in there.

```
class Service {

  constructor (options) {
    this.options = options || {};
  }

  async find (params) {

    console.log(params);
  ..
  .
```